# Can't get headers from Azure Durable API

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions, azure-management-api

I'm calling Azure durable function management API from my client-side code. Since it's a CORS request, the code won't let me see any relevant headers (I need the continuation token because I need to get more than one page of log records). CORS is enabled in Azure and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set to true, I use `withCredentials` on the client side, but I still can't get any relevant headers. I wonder what I am doing wrong here.

Is there any chance to do it on the client, or should I use a server-side proxy?

Comment: In this case, since you are facing limitations with CORS headers and the continuation token is required for fetching multiple pages of log records, using a server-side proxy would be a recommended approach. By using a server-side proxy, you can make requests to the Azure durable function management API from your server-side code instead of directly from the client-side code. This way, you can bypass the CORS restrictions and retrieve the necessary headers, including the continuation token.

Comment: Yes, I ended up with a server-side proxy.

I just wonder why my Azure setup didn't work for me.